# jmh No matching benchmarks. Miss-spelled regexp? Use -v for verbose output.

Tags: java, jmh

I'm implementing sample application for my understanding of JMH. i was having issue while running it. I found this error

```
No matching benchmarks. Miss-spelled regexp? Use -v for verbose output.
```

here is my code.

```
public class TestJMS {



   @GenerateMicroBenchmark
   public void wellHelloThere() {

   }



   public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
       Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
               .include(".*" + TestJMS.class.getSimpleName() + ".*")
               .forks(1)
               .build();

       new Runner(opt).run();
   }

}
```

I found many postes related to this issue, but no answer there clear to me. please explain in simple manner.

Comment: Did you use annotation processor to actually generate the benchmark?

Comment: Please follow the instructions on JMH page (http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), and build the benchmark uberjar with Maven -- forget about `main()` method.